# Can the parameter space of a single parameter exponential family in canonical form be a closed interval?

Tags: exponential-family

I know that the parameter space has to be convex (that I've proved using Jensen's inequality). Therefore, since it has to be a subset of $\mathbb R$, it follows that it has to be an interval or a point. Assuming that it is not a point, is it possible that the parameter space $\mathcal N$ for one-parameter exponential family distribution in canonical form, i.e. one with the following density:
\begin{equation}
f_\theta(x) = C(\theta)h(x)e^{\theta T(x)}
\end{equation}
is a closed interval?

Comment: $\mathbb{R}$ is a closed interval.

Comment: @whuber, $\mathbb R$ is both open and closed in $\mathbb R$ trivially. In this case, by closed interval,  I mean some non-trivial case like $[a,b]$ where $-\infty<a<b<\infty$

Comment: $[0,1]$ for the Binomial distribution.

Comment: If you want to rule out cases then you need to do so explicitly in your question.  Otherwise the trivial answer(s) are valid.

Comment: @Xi'an For binomial distribution, $[0,1]$ is not correct, because the natural parameter is $\log\left[\frac{p}{1-p}\right]$, whose natural parameter space is $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: The Binomial distribution is well defined for $p=0,1$.

Comment: True, but OP is about the natural parameter space of $\theta$, which is the natural parameter (because p.d.f is form of $e^{t\theta}$). $p$ is a not the natural parameter so $[0,1]$ is not the natural parameter space.